# securing access to spring cloud configserver

Tags: spring, configuration, spring-cloud

I was wondering how people are handling security aspects when using Spring Cloud Config.
I'm planning to use Spring Cloud Config Server and Client together with Spring Boot. From an implementation point of view this is quite straight, but how do you deal with the risk of disclosing password/access to every developer. 
e.g. you run one central configserver containing configurations for all environment. In the `bootstrap.yml` of the config client app you'll have to configure the `username`/`password` to access the configserver. So far so good, but when I know commit the username/password in the respective yml file, then every developer has potential access to all environments by just switching the profile from e.g. `development` to `production` (please let's not start a discussion why not every developer needs access to production).

I'm aware that I can encrypt all passwords in the configuration, we do this, but that's not what I'm looking for. Encryption is just a feature to not have the passwords being stored plaintext in the files, but the user does not really need to know the plain password to get access if he has access to the configserver in the first place.

This is also about avoiding mistakes during development... its just to easy to switch the local environment to connect to production or any other environment.

So how are people dealing with this? Do you inject a different `bootstrap.yml` in development then in other environments? if so how do you administrate/propagate these?

Do you set the password for the configuration user on the comandline?
...?

Comment: If your developers don't own production, then production config should be in a repository they don't have access to.

Comment: and how you deal with it? do you have multiple configservers? and in define the correct configserver at startup as CLI argument? The one thing I'm a bit missing is that who ever has access to the configserver can see all the configuration. I think there should be support for multiple users who can see only parts (e.g. profiles) of the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

We use variables and default values for config server URL, user and password

${config_username:user}:${config_password:password}@${config_server:conf.mydomain.com}

Default values can be valid credentials for development environment this way you simply run it while you develop. When you deploy to production simply set those environment variables and your application will connect to a different config server

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking about this myself and came up with 3 options.  In all cases, use {cipher} values in repos for sensitive data and disable various actuator endpoints that would allow decryption or property value lists.

1. Have two config servers, one for dev and one for prod, with no dev access to the prod server, controlled by credentials provided to the prod client at runtime.
2. Perform the decryption client side, using a secret provided to the prod client at runtime.
3. Explicitly define a prod profile and block access to URLs containing that profile from non-prod servers.